# URL rewrite SEO question - multi shop

Tags: multistore, 301-redirect

I have a Multi webshop installation with 3 existing shops. They have their products.
Now I want to migrate an OSCommerce shop to Magento and add as 4th shop.
About 50% of the products are shared between the new shop and the existing Magento shops. Just different names, descriptions, amounts.
I want to keep the SEO/ranking of the OSCommerce products when moving to Magento.

However, these products have already their permanent re-direct enabled in product maintenance. The problem I see is that the URL-key is only at a global level and not on the shop level.
Is there any way I can keep the re-directs as currently maintained in Magento for the 3 shops already AND also add a 301 re-direct from the OSCommerce to the new Magento product for the 4th shop?

example:
product URL existing Magento shop "1":
sony-Bravia-8100.html

existing OSCommerce URL
LED-Bravia-sony-8100.html

I want to keep sony-Bravia-8100.html (as this has its own ranking and is applicable for shop 1, but I also want to have for the same product in Magento for shop 4 the re-direct from LED-Bravia-sony-8100.html.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. We also migrated 4 unique shops in to Magento 1.6.2 multi store. After hat we just turned on mod rewrite. [Here is a article](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/664-fixing-url-rewrites-with-magento) how you do it in admin mod rewrite.

Don't forget that if you have back links from the OSC time, you ned to find them and do a 301 redirect so you don't loose the links.

I hope it helps. And it's late here so I'm not sure if I forgot something.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions we've implemented was to use a url rewrite php file included in index.php. It would act as a translator for legacy urls and direct to the storefronts as needed.